# Se duplica la barra de navegación cuando hago una petición AJAX en el formulario de login

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5, django

¡Buenas a todos!, tengo un problema que no sé cómo resolver, estoy tratando de hacer una petición AJAX por medio de jQuery para evitar que la página se refresque cuando el usuario quiera ingresar por medio del formulario, el problema es que cuando le doy en "Iniciar sesión", la barra de navegación se me duplica.

Tampoco me redirecciona a la URL que le paso, y cuando ocurre el error de autenticación es que se duplica la barra de navegación, Cabe aclarar que estoy usando el framework Django de Python.

**Anexo una imagen del resultado**

[image: navbar duplicado]

**Codigo HTML de la barra de navegación**

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/logo_brand.png' %}" alt="logo_brand.png" width="250" height="40"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-decoration-none" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'home' %}">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-decoration-none" href="{% url 'about' %}">Sobre nosotros</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-decoration-none" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="far fa-user"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'login' %}">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'register' %}">Registrarse</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"><i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i> Ingresar como Administrador</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Mi formulario en HTML**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}Login de sesión{% endblock %}

{% block extra_styles %}
        <script src="{% static 'jQuery/jquery-3.7.1.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/login.css' %}"> 
{% endblock %}


{% block content%}
<form id="login-form" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <section class="vh-50 gradient-custom py-5">
    <div class="container py-5 h-100">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
          <div class="card bg-dark bg-gradient text-white" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
            <div class="card-body p-5 text-center">
              <div class="mb-md-5 mt-md-4 pb-5">
                <h2 class="fw-bold mb-2 text-uppercase"><img src="{% static 'images/logo_brand.png' %}" alt="logo_brand.png" width="250" height="40"></h2>
                <p class="text-white-50 mb-5 py-2">Por favor, ingresa tu contraseña de ingreso!</p>
                <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                  <label class="form-label" for="username"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Nombre de usuario</label>
                  <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="username"  placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre de usuario">
                </div>
                <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                  <label class="form-label" for="password"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> Contraseña</label>
                  <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-5" type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-center mt-4 pt-1" id="content-result">
                  {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> {{ message }}
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif%}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="mb-0">¿No tienes una cuenta? <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="text-white-50 fw-bold text-decoration-none">Registrate</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
<script src="{% static 'js/login_form.js' %}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**Codigo de petición AJAX**

```js
// Aplicando AJAX al formulario de login para evitar que se refresque la pagina.
$(document).on("submit", "#login-form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("se clickeo")
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '/login/',
        data: {
            username: $("input[name='username']").val(),
            password: $("input[name='password']").val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
        // Eliminar los datos de entrada de los inputs cuando se hace submit. 
        $("input[name='username']").val("")
        $("input[name='password']").val("")
        alert("Sesion!")
        $('#login-form').html(data)
    
      },

      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("error de respuesta", error)
      }

      });
```

**Rutas de las vistas**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', view=views.home_page, name="home"),
    path('login/', view=views.user_login, name="login"),
    path('register/', view=views.user_registration, name="register"),
    path('change_password/', view=views.restart_password, name="change_password"),
    path('logout/', view=views.user_logout, name="logout"),
    path('about/', view=views.about_us, name="about"),
    

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema? Sería de gran ayuda si me colaboraran, ¡gracias!

Comment: Y el código de la barra de navegación?

Comment: Ya lo agregué, ¿Cuál sería el problema de la duplicidad al hacer la petición?

Comment: Supongo que la url `'/login/'` corresponde al segundo código. Lo que pasa es que esa plantilla ya tiene la barra de navegación. Prueba poner `$('body').html(data)` dentro del ajax (en lugar de `$('#login-form').html(data)`)